# "order" function in R is not working properly with repeated values

Tags: r

It looks like "order" function is not working properly with repeated values. For example, check the code below. As you can see, same elemets have a different order.

Is there any way to fix this?

```
special <- c(0.8612482, 0.1728704, 0.1728704, 0.6933106, 0.4718281, 0.4718281, 0.8275597,
                 0.3934772, 0.3934772, 0.6777266, 0.2526969, 0.0605038, 0.7352600, 0.7352600,
                 2.2376845, 0.8814698, 2.7420961, 2.7420961, 1.5314565, 1.4855230)
special[8]
order(special)[8]

special[9]
order(special)[9]
```

Comment: Try `?rank` maybe?

Comment: Why do you think that's not working properly?  One of the basic properties of `order()` is that it returns a permutation:  it *shouldn't* include duplicate indices.

Comment: jay.sf, thank you, that is exactly what I looked for.

Comment: also thanks to user2554330 for explanation of order specifics

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you are looking for is `sort()` not `order()`.

```
sort(special)[8]
0.4718281
```

sort():

> Sort (or order) a vector or factor (partially) into ascending or
> descending order. For ordering along more than one variable, e.g., for
> sorting data frames, see order.

order():

> order returns a permutation which rearranges its first argument into
> ascending or descending order, breaking ties by further arguments.
> sort.list is the same, using only one argument.